# Is there a way to avoid conflict from using GoogleSignIn and AppAuth-iOS as static framework?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-signin, appauth

Our project use `Carthage` as dependency manager and use that to get `AppAuth-iOS`

For `GoogleSignIn`, we download `GoogleSignIn` from [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks) and drag it to the project directly

However, there is a conflict between `AppAuth` install via Carthage with `AppAuth` from `GoogleSignIn`

Is there any other workaround to overcome this conflict without folk `AppAuth` and rename all class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `AppAuth` from the Cartfile and only use the one from the GoogleSignIn folder at the download location.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I don't know why I'm not consider this before... I will try maybe sometime later next week